# Angular Custom Directive .match is not a function

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-templates

I am trying to create a simple angular radio-group directive.  the component will be passed an array of strings, an id, and an attribute to bind the selected option to. When I run my code I get the following error

> angular.js:13642TypeError: a.match is not a function

here is what I have:
app.js:

```
angular.module('atp', [])
.directive('appform', require('./application-directive'))
.directive('radioGroup', require('./radio-group/radio-group-directive'))
.directive('yesNoRadioGroup', require('./radio-group/yes-no-radio-group-directive'));
```

radio-group-directive.js:

```
function RadioGroupDirective(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        transclude:true,
        template:require('./radio-group-template.html'),
        replace:true,
        scope:{
            id:'=',
            selected:'=',
            options:'='
        }
     }
}
module.exports = RadioGroupDirective;
```

radio-group-template.html:

```
<div>
    <label for="{{radioGroupId}}"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></label>
    <fieldset id="{{radioGroupId}}">
        <div ng-repeat="option in optionsArray track by $index">
            <label for="{{radioGroupId}}-{{$index}}">{{option}}</label>
            <input  id="{{radioGroupId}}-{{$index}}" type="radio" value="option" ng-model="selectedOption">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

yes-no-radio-group-directive.js:

```
function YesNoRadioGroupDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude:true,
        template: require('./radio-group-template.html'),
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            RadioGroupId: '=',
            selectedOption: '=',
            optionsArray: ['Yes', 'No']
        }
    }
}
module.exports = YesNoRadioGroupDirective;
```

usage:

```
<form>
    <yes-no-radio-group radio-group-id="test" selected-option="Controller.Form.SelectedYesNo">Select Yes or No:</yes-no-radio-group>
    <radio-group radio-group-id="test-radio" options-array="['Hello World','Some Other Option']" selected="Controller.Form.SelectedYesNo">Select one of the options:</radio-group>
</form>
```

Comment: `template` must return a string. No need for `require`. Use templateUrl and angular will fetch it for you

Comment: see my comment below.  the template require is not the problem.  it translates the require directly into a template: "<div>...</div>"

Comment: So where in the stack trace is error started?

Comment: angular.js:7510  `var match = definition.match(LOCAL_REGEXP);`

Comment: That doesn't indicate where the stack starts

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this? You don't need require at first `instance` and secondly if you are requiring a html, u need `templateUrl` instead of template

```
template:require('./radio-group-template.html'),
```

Comment: I am using web pack, and html-loader.  the require('*.html) loads the file as a string.  https://github.com/webpack/html-loader